# Spring servlet-mapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

friends.
I'm not good at English. Please Understand it.

I was asked to make a xml file.

When I access below address with a browser. I should see below xml.
**http://localhost:8080/update/update.jsp**

```
<update_info app_name="ktp_app" version="2012031001" count="">
  <apache_start version="20120310011255" type="bat" reg="123123" size="423">
  <remote>http://192.168.0.1/ka/apache_start.bat</remote>
  <remote>apache_start.bat</remote>
  </apache_start>
</update_info>
```

but, in web.xml
I have this setting.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.byto</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

with above, I could process all my other request with spring controller which look like this.

```
@Controller
public class DownloadManageController {

    @Autowired
    private DownloadManageService downService;

    @RequestMapping("/ajax/add_download_hour")
    public void addDownloadHour(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, InvalidHourRangeException, IOException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {
        downService.addDownloadLimit(
            request.getParameter("app_cmd"),
            request.getParameter("start_hour"),
            request.getParameter("end_hour"), 
            request.getParameter("limit_count"));
    }
    ...
}
```

But I also have this controller.

```
@Controller
public class UpdateXmlController extends HttpServlet {

    @Autowired
    private UpdateXmlService updateService;

    @RequestMapping("/update")
    protected ModelAndView getUpdateData(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String cmd = request.getParameter("cmd");
        Map resultMap = null;
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        try {
            resultMap = updateService.getUpdateData(cmd);
            request.setAttribute("server", resultMap.get("server"));
            request.setAttribute("package", resultMap.get("package"));
            request.setAttribute("file", resultMap.get("file"));
        } catch(NoCmdException ex) {
            return new ModelAndView("error_page", "errorMsg", ex.getMessage());
        } catch(DownloadCountExceedException ex) {
            return new ModelAndView("error_page", "errorMsg", ex.getMessage());
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            //System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            //response.getWriter().write();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new ModelAndView("update", "result", resultMap);
    }

}
```

which i need to access with **http://localhost:8080/update/update.jsp** .

But, I only way to access that controller is with http://localhost:8080/update/update.byto

**So, here's my QUESTION**

how could I access that controller with .jsp address.

thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you *want* to access it with a `.jsp` suffix?

Comment: I see  your controllers contain too many *request.getParameter()**s, I believe you are not utilizing Spring MVC well.

Comment: I think so, i knew Spring a few days ago and I started programming a few months ago.

Comment: Mr. skaffman, I need that because my senior wants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporarily, I solved this problem with JSP file.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=EUC-KR"
    pageEncoding="EUC-KR"%>
<%
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/update.byto").forward(request, response);
%>
```

**above source will dispatch all information to Spring controller.**

Answer (score 1):

Could you add another servlet-mapping?

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.byto</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Why does the URL need to be **http://localhost:8080/update/update.jsp**?

**EDIT -** As skaffman points out, this will result in an infinite loop. I'll leave this answer in place as an example of what **not** to do!

As an example of what happens in Tomcat:

```
09-Mar-2012 16:49:11 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Test threw exception
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.HashMap.getEntry(HashMap.java:344)
    at java.util.HashMap.containsKey(HashMap.java:335)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.removeAttribute(Request.java:1335)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.removeAttribute(RequestFacade.java:514)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.removeAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.removeAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:256)

...

at test.Test.doGet(Test.java:27)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
at test.Test.doGet(Test.java:27)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
```

Comment: If you do that, then when the controller forwards to the JSP, it'll get caught in an infinite loop.

Comment: some program which my senior already made has static update path "http://localhost:8080/update/update.jsp"

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
@Controller("/update")
...

  @RequestMapping("/update.jsp")
```

Comment: That won't work, because the `web.xml` defines the URL pattern as `*.byto`, so `.jsp` won't be directed to Spring.